# A few icons in the screenshot are obsolete in the community wiki help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

In each site's [Create Wiki Posts - Privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) page,
under **How do Community Wiki posts work?** section there is a screenshot that shows the position of the **community wiki** check box.

The main intention of the screenshot is to point out where the **community wiki** is placed in the screen only, but a few editor toolbar icons in the screenshot are obsolete.

That help center page should be updated to use the current version of the editor toolbar icons.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Current toolbar icons need to be update in help center page]

Comment: -1 no freehand circles.

Comment: Note that if you look through the whole help centre, there are so many outdated screenshots. This is just one of a few.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed and the screenshots have been removed.

There's been a trend to not rely on screenshots in the Help Center and remove them because every time a design element changed the screenshots, and thus the info in the Help Center, become outdated.